# How to call protocol from another viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, protocols

I want to call `protocol` to my `viewController` from another `viewController`. I got error like below:

> Type 'Hello' does not conform to protocol 'loginpageVCDelegate'

Here is my protocol in `loginpageVC`

```
protocol loginpageVCDelegate {
    func onLoginFacebook(loginViewController : loginpageVC!)
}
```

And here is how I call it

```
class Hello : UIViewController, loginpageVCDelegate {
   ....
}
```

What did I do wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: In your login view controller, in the method where after login you want to inform/notify Hello class that hello class has to do some task through onLoginFacebook method. You have to set delegate in the login VC as helloObject.delegate = self.

Answer (score 1):

You should not call it here but instead implement it:

```
class Hello : UIViewController, loginpageVCDelegate {
    func onLoginFacebook(loginViewController: loginpageVC!) {

    }
}
```

Comment: but I already implement that on loginpageVC, am I have to reimplement on the Hello?

Comment: Protocol declaration says that specified class implements all methods from protocol. If you don't need that just remove protocol declaration from Hello

Comment: I need that protocol, what I need is how can I call that protocol without error?

Comment: If you have implemented that on `loginpageVC` you may safely call `onLoginFacebook` on some instance of `loginpageVC`

Comment: So I can call onLoginFacebook on Hello without calling loginpageVCDelegate protocol?

Comment: No, you can't call `onLoginFacebook` on `Hello` without implementing it

Answer (score 1):

To make the implementation of the function from your protocol optional, modify your protocol in `loginpageVC` to:

```
@objc protocol loginpageVCDelegate {
    optional func onLoginFacebook(loginViewController : loginpageVC!) 
}
```